In my flutter app when I open project in mac m1 and run app in IOS devices the assets images is not load in whole app
I have create Flutter Project in windows OS but for the IOS setup I move on mac OS and I Run the app on IOS virtual Device the assets images is not load.
I check the Pod install And update it. and also check gem version.

Case sensitive file path/names can cause this, could you check this?
MacOS is more strict about this.
